# Binding visibility to task status

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm binding the visibility of a ProgressBar to a property that returns true if a specific task is running:

View:

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" 
             Visibility="{Binding TaskRunning, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private Task someTask;
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

public bool TaskRunning
{
    get
    {
        return someTask!= null && someTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running;
    }
}

private void StartTaskHandler()
{
    someTask = Task.Run(new Action(() =>
    {
         // Simulate some work
         cancellationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(10000);
    }), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    someTask.ContinueWith((task) => RaisePropertyChanged("TaskRunning"));
    RaisePropertyChanged("TaskRunning");
}
```

When executing `StartTaskHandler` the ProgressBar will only sometimes turn visible. Why is that? How can I make sure the ProgressBar is visible when the task is running?

Comment: I think you need to read into Asynchronous design. This website really helped me https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`someTask.Status` may sometimes be still `TaskStatus.WaitingToRun`. Adding this will solve the issue. But it's better to use async/await:

```
private bool isBusy = false;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get
    {
        return isBusy;
    }
    set
    {
        isBusy = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusy");
    }
}

private async void StartTaskHandler()
{
    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    IsBusy = true;
    someTask = Task.Run(new Action(() =>
    {
        // Simulate some work
        cancellationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(10000);
    }), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    await someTask;
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to you to rename your property `TaskRunning` to `IsBusy` as it is good practice to name `bool` variables with prefix `is`.

You should have setter in your property TaskRunning to set `true` value:

```
private bool _isBusy;
public bool IsBusy
{
  get { return _isBusy; }
  set
    {
       _isBusy = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusy");
    }
}
```

and at your code:

```
private void StartTaskHandler()
{
   IsBusy=true;
   someTask = Task.Run(new Action(() =>
   {
       // Simulate some work
       cancellationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(10000);
   }), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
   someTask.ContinueWith((task) => IsBusy=false;);       
}
```

You can raise `PropertyChanged event` from any threads cause WPF automatically dispatches arguments of `PropertyChanged event` to the UI thread.

**Update:**

**Your code does not work as your property `TaskRunning` is just readable, and you** cannot set `true` or `false` values. To set values to your property you should add setter and fire an event PropertyChanged when you set new value to the property `TaskRunning`:

```
private bool _taskRunning;
public bool TaskRunning
{
  get
    {
        if(someTask!= null && someTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
           _taskRunning=true;
       return _taskRunning;
    }
  set
    {
       _taskRunning=value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("TaskRunning");
    }
}
```

**This row of code just fires the event with the current value(not new value):**

```
someTask.ContinueWith((task) => RaisePropertyChanged("TaskRunning"));
```

but this row of code will set new value of property `TaskRunning` and fires event `PropertyChanged` to update your UI:

```
someTask.ContinueWith((task) => TaskRunning=true;);
```

Comment: IsBusy is better, thanks. Your code will not work, the task is running asynchronous, and IsBusy will be set to false befroe the task ends

Comment: @FabianH.  IsBusy is set at continuation of your Task. So IsBusy will be updated after finishing your Task. Have you tried the code?

Comment: I see you edited your code, this works, thanks. I still don't get why my code is not working. When I call 'RaisePropertyChanged' at the end of 'StartTaskHandler', the task should have status Running.

Comment: @FabianH. please see my updated answer. If my reply solves your task, you can mark it as an answer to simplify search to other people. Feel free to ask questions:)

Comment: I'm sorry but your edit is not true. someTask.ContinueWith((task) => RaisePropertyChanged("TaskRunning")); works as intended.

Comment: @StepUp Nice answer. I'm assuming the OP's `RaisePropertyChanged` method just fires a `PropertyChanged` event for the specified property. If so, that would cause the value of the property to be read again by the WPF binding system even though it is a read-only property.

Comment: `RaisePropertyChanged` is the one from mvvm-light (hence the mvvm-light flag), so it does just fire a `PropertyChanged` event. The Problem was that the task had still status `WaitingToRun` when the `PropertyChanged` event was fired. Could have fixed it by adding `WaitingToRun` but I think async/await is better (See my own anser). Thanks for the help.